# Docker - MySQL container does not keep running

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, fig

I need some help with using MySQL in a Docker container. I thought the entire point of Docker was to isolate processes in sandboxes and have them run like normal processes - I am not getting this functionality.

Whenever I run a MySQL container that I have built from my own image, it runs for 2 seconds, then stops. Trying `docker run -i -t <imageid>` gives me this:

```
root@CenturionX:/home/centurionx/Code/Git/gdms-rcon# docker run -i -t e2d
150221 05:25:21 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/28123b6d1dad.err'.
150221 05:25:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150221 05:25:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
root@CenturionX:/home/centurionx/Code/Git/gdms-rcon#
```

Why does the daemon not stay open? I have my `Dockerfile`, which looks like:

```
# This docker file constructs a MySQL database instance
FROM mysql:latest

ADD . /gdms-rcon/mysql
WORKDIR /gdms-rcon/mysql

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mysqld_safe"]

EXPOSE 3306
```

And a `fig.yml` file to help me automate the build process:

```
mysql:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - .:/gdms-rcon/mysql
  working_dir: /gdms-rcon/mysql
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mysql official image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) have a `/entrypoint.sh` script that is needed to run when you start the image in order to configure and running the container correctly. It seems that running `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe` instead doesn't configure correctly mysql and the process `mysqld_safe` ends, so the container also ends.

Try replacing your `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
# This docker file constructs a MySQL database instance
FROM mysql:latest

ADD . /gdms-rcon/mysql
WORKDIR /gdms-rcon/mysql

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
```